# Window is full requested allocation error

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-cursor

I have two services one of them use sensors and the other one use GPS. I have one database. When I combine them I get average sensor values and write them GPS line. To get average I count db. But after a while application does not work. It gives that error.

> Blockquote W/CursorWindow(2852): Window is full: requested allocation 228 bytes, free space 156 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
>   Blockquote

Is there any possibility to clear cache or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GPSDataContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String TAG = "GPSDataContentProvider";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "semgpsdata.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String POINT_TABLE_NAME = "gpspoints";

public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.semih";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/gpspoint");



private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "gpspoint", DATABASE_VERSION);
}

/**
 * This class helps open, create, and upgrade the database file.
 */
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     try {
     Log.i(TAG, "Creating table " + POINT_TABLE_NAME);    
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + POINT_TABLE_NAME + " ("
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.LATITUDE + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.LONGITUDE + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.PRESSURE + " DOUBLE,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.BHEIGHT + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.TEMPERATURE + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.HUMIDITY + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.FLOOR + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.ADDRESS + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.PROVIDER + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.SAT + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.SPEED + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.ACCURACY + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.USER + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.PHONE + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.ESAY + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.SAY + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.KNTRL + " REAL,"
             + GPSData.GPSPoint.TIME + " INTEGER"
             + ");");
     } catch (SQLiteException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + POINT_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public int getDbCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + POINT_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    } 

    public void deleteDb(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(POINT_TABLE_NAME, GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    public double getPressure (int rowID) {
        double uname = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String where= GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID;
        String order = GPSData.GPSPoint.PRESSURE;

        Cursor mCursor= db.query (POINT_TABLE_NAME, null, where, null, null, null,order); 

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                uname = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GPSData.GPSPoint.PRESSURE));

            }

            mCursor.close();

            return uname;

    }

    public double getBHeight (int rowID) {
        double uname1 = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String where= GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID;
        String order = GPSData.GPSPoint.BHEIGHT;

        Cursor mCursor= db.query (POINT_TABLE_NAME, null, where, null, null, null,order); 

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                uname1 = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GPSData.GPSPoint.BHEIGHT));

            }
            mCursor.close();
            return uname1;

    }

    public double getTemp (int rowID) {
        double uname2 = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String where= GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID;
        String order = GPSData.GPSPoint.TEMPERATURE;

        Cursor mCursor= db.query (POINT_TABLE_NAME, null, where, null, null, null,order); 

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                uname2 = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GPSData.GPSPoint.TEMPERATURE));

            }
            mCursor.close();
            return uname2;

    }

    public double getHumidity (int rowID) {
        double uname3 = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String where= GPSData.GPSPoint.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID;
        String order = GPSData.GPSPoint.HUMIDITY;

        Cursor mCursor= db.query (POINT_TABLE_NAME, null, where, null, null, null,order); 

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                uname3 = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GPSData.GPSPoint.HUMIDITY));

            }
            mCursor.close();
            return uname3;

    }


}

private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;


public boolean onCreate() {
    mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}


@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return 0;
 }


 @Override
 public String getType(Uri uri) {
 Log.i(TAG, "getting type for " + uri.toString());
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
 }


 @Override
 public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
 Log.e(TAG, "inserting value " + values.toString());

    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 long rowId = db.insert(POINT_TABLE_NAME, "", values);
     if (rowId > 0) {
         Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(GPSDataContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
         getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(noteUri, null);
         return noteUri;
     }

     throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}


  @Override
 public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
 String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

  return null;
  }


  @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
   String[] selectionArgs) {

   return 0;
}
}
```